# How to extract certain columns from a big Notepad text file?

Tags: notepad

I have a big text file and the data in it are in 5 columns, but I need just the first and the last column of that.

It will take many days and probably with mistake if I want to enter the data of this two column one-by-one from here to another file.
Is there a fast way to do this?
For example:

```
     1   1.0000000000000000         0.0000000000 S {0}
     2   1.5000000000000000         0.3010299957 C {2}
     3   1.7500000000000000         0.6020599913 S {0,2}
     4   2.0000000000000000         0.7781512504 C {3}
     5   2.3333333333333333         1.0791812460 C {3,2}
     6   2.5000000000000000         1.3802112417 S {3,0,2}
     7   2.5277777777777778         1.5563025008 S {0,3}
     8   2.5833333333333333         1.6812412374 S {3,0,0,2}
     9   2.8000000000000000         1.7781512504 C {5,2}
    10   3.0000000000000000         2.0791812460 C {5,0,2}
```

I need the first column (numbering) and the last inside {  }.

Comment: It's called a _text file_.

Comment: See SLaks. Pretty much anything that can handle text can do this (which is again pretty much everything), without notepad. Languages like Perl or Python or Ruby (or good old unix command line tools) propably take the least amount of code, choose whatever you have installed.

Comment: I third this.  This fundamentally has nothing to do with Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import it into Excel and manipulate it there.

Answer (score 8):

`ALT` + `Left Mouse Click` puts you in *Column Mode Select*. It's quite an useful shortcut that may help you.

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution. Copy the file, edit the copy, cut out the non-needed columns.

Answer (score 5):

in Notepad++, you can use regular expression to do replacement:

the regex for find and replace is:

`^( +\d+).+\{([\d,]+)\}$`

`\1 \2`

[image]

then can change the:

```
 1   1.0000000000000000         0.0000000000 S {0}
 2   1.5000000000000000         0.3010299957 C {2}
 3   1.7500000000000000         0.6020599913 S {0,2}
 4   2.0000000000000000         0.7781512504 C {3}
 5   2.3333333333333333         1.0791812460 C {3,2}
 6   2.5000000000000000         1.3802112417 S {3,0,2}
 7   2.5277777777777778         1.5563025008 S {0,3}
 8   2.5833333333333333         1.6812412374 S {3,0,0,2}
 9   2.8000000000000000         1.7781512504 C {5,2}
10   3.0000000000000000         2.0791812460 C {5,0,2}
```

to:

```
     1 0
     2 2
     3 0,2
     4 3
     5 3,2
     6 3,0,2
     7 0,3
     8 3,0,0,2
     9 5,2
    10 5,0,2
```

[image]

if not want the leading space, then use:

`^( +\d+).+\{([\d,]+)\}$`

`\1 \2`

will change to:

```
1 0
2 2
3 0,2
4 3
5 3,2
6 3,0,2
7 0,3
8 3,0,0,2
9 5,2
10 5,0,2
```

Comment: Replacement with regular expression rules! Use it all the times. Good and very detailed answer pal!

Answer (score 4):

You should use `awk` or `gawk` which is available on windows platform also. Use `gawk "{print $1,$5}" inpfile > outfile`. I copied your file named it 'one'. You can see the output which consists of 1st and 5th column of your file.

```
>gawk "{print $1, $5}"  one
1 {0}
2 {2}
3 {0,2}
4 {3}
5 {3,2}
6 {3,0,2}
7 {0,3}
8 {3,0,0,2}
9 {5,2}
10 {5,0,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET, [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) may save you a lot of time. From your post we can't tell what technology you are hoping to use to accomplish this.

Comment: my original file is in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Ultraedit has a tool for selecting columns and opens large files (I tried a 900 Mb file on a 2008 desktop and it opened in 3 minutes). I think it has a demo version fully operational. 
Excel could work if you do not have too many rows.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to copy the data to MS word file. 
Then use

{Alt + left mouse click}

Then you can drag on the selected column and you can see only a single column is selected.
Copy and paste wherever you want.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one way to convolve ungodly amounts of data. That is with the command prompt.

```
$cat text.txt | sed 's/{.*,//;s/  */ /g;s/[{}]//g' | awk '{print $1","$5}' > clean_text.csv
```

This 15 second fix is not available in Windows OS.  It will take you less time to download and install Linux on that old dead computer in your closet than it will to get your data in and out of Excel.

Happy coding!